# Merging Hot Flux Sources

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In Spring Boot 2 with Reactor, I am attempting to merge two `Flux` hot sources. However, the `merge` only ever seems to report the first of the two `Flux` parameters in `merge`. How do I get the `merge` to recognize the second `Flux`.

In the example below, the `System.err` in `B-2` doesn't even print when `outgoing1a` is the first parameter. If I make `outgoing2` the first, then `A-2` doesn't print.

Below is the full example;

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class Weather {
String city;
Integer temperature;

public Weather(String city, Integer temperature) {
    this.city = city;
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Weather [city=" + city + ", temperature=" + temperature + "]";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue<Weather> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BlockingQueue<Weather> queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    // Assume Spring @Repository "A-1"
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int d = 1; d < 1000; d += 1) {
            for (String s: new String[] {"LDN", "NYC", "PAR", "ZUR"}) {
                queue.add(new Weather(s, d));
                try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }).start(); 

    // Assume Spring @Repository "B-1"
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int d = 1; d < 1000; d += 1) {
            for (String s: new String[] {"MOS", "TLV"}) {
                queue2.add(new Weather(s, d));
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // Assume Spring @Service "A-2" = real-time LDN, NYC, PAR, ZUR
    Flux<Weather> outgoing1 = Flux.<Weather>create(
        sink -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                try {
                    sink.next(queue.take());
                    System.err.println("1 " + queue.size());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            sink.complete();
        }
    ).publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("outgoing-1"));

    // Assume Spring @Service "B-2" = real-time MOS, TLV
    Flux<Weather> outgoing2 = Flux.<Weather>create(
            sink -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    try {
                        sink.next(queue2.take());
                        System.err.println("2 " + queue2.size());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                sink.complete();
            }
        ).publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("outgoing-2"));

    // Assume Spring @Service "A-3" = 5 second summary of LDN, NYC, PAR, ZUR
    Flux<Weather> outgoing1a = Flux.from(outgoing1)   
        .groupBy(c -> c.city)
        .flatMap(g -> g
            .sample(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        )
        .log("C");

    // Assume Spring @Service "C" - merges "A-3" and "B-2"
    // only prints outgoing1a
    Flux.merge(outgoing1a, outgoing2).subscribe(System.out::println); 

    // only prints outgoing2
    //Flux.merge(outgoing2, outgoing1a).subscribe(System.out::println); 

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things at play here.

1. Note the following recommendation of the [`.merge`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) operator...

> Note that merge is tailored to work with asynchronous sources or finite sources. When dealing with an infinite source that doesn't already publish on a dedicated Scheduler, you must isolate that source in its own Scheduler, as merge would otherwise attempt to drain it before subscribing to another source.

2. Your outbound Fluxes use `.publishOn`, but that only affects operators chained *after* the `.publishOn` operator.  i.e. It doesn't affect anything *before* the `.publishOn`.  Specifically, it does not affect the thread on which the code in lambda passed to `Flux.create` executes. You can see this if you add `.log()` *before* the `.publishOn` in each of the outbound Fluxes.
3. Your lambda passed to `Flux.create` calls a blocking method (`queue.take`).

Since you call `subscribe(...)` on the merged Flux in the `main` thread, your lambda passed to `Flux.create` executes in the `main` thread, and blocks it.

The easiest fix is to use `.subscribeOn` instead of `.publishOn` so that your code in the lambda passed to `Flux.create` operates on a different thread (other than `main`).  This will prevent the `main` thread from blocking, and allow the merged output from both outbound streams to be interleaved.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. `subscribeOn` instead or `publishOn` did indeed fix the issue. I will play with the `Thread.sleep()` which writes to the `BlockingQueue` and a `delay()` after the `merge()` to see which flavor of `subscribeOn` I will ultimately need.